# Inserting/deleting a large amount of records at once in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, bulk

I am looking to insert about 100,000 records (of just pre-defined ID numbers) into a new table (table 1) in SQL, and then create a delete statement which looks at those records in the new table (table 1), to delete matching records in a different table (table 2), which would be the primary key in the second table (table 2).

When inserting or deleting this amount of records, should I be concerned with bogging down the server? Can a query like such (with this amount of records, or say 10 million records) actually shut down SQL Server (or the server itself)?

I'm not too familiar with SQL query performance stuff, and I don't want to just run a query to insert or delete a large amount of records if it could have serious consequences.

Comment: Any transaction that has more than 5000 inserts, updates, deletes will do a lock escalation (from row-level locks) and exclusively lock the entire table, for the duration of the transaction (until you commit - or roll back). So you should always try to do your bulk operations in chunks of less than 5000 rows

Comment: Hi @marc_s thanks, is there a simple query so it deletes chunks of 5000 records at a time in this type of case? I was thinking something like DELETE FROM table1 WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM table2)